# Table added to PDF using ItextSharp is missing

Tags: c#, itext

I was searching through known questions and answers regarding ItextSharp and adding table to PDF by using this library, but no one has similar issue.

This is my code:

```
 foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry item in fields.Fields)
            {
                    AcroFields.Item acroFieldItem = fields.GetFieldItem(FieldName);
                    PdfDictionary formFieldsValues = (PdfDictionary)acroFieldItem.values[0];

                    string defaultFieldValue = "";
                    if (formFieldsValues.Contains(PdfName.DV))
                    {
                        defaultFieldValue = formFieldsValues.Get(PdfName.DV).ToString();
                    }

                    int startIndex = defaultFieldValue.IndexOf("<%", 0);

                    if (startIndex != -1)
                    {

                        string FieldNameValue = TemplatesParser.Parse(defaultFieldValue, fieldDataSet);
                        string tableName = TemplatesParser.GetElementName(defaultFieldValue).Replace(":::", "");

                        if (tableNames.Contains(tableName))
                        {
                            foreach (int i in tableIndexes)
                            {
                                //var dt = new DataTable();
                               var expression = "ShowInTable = '" + tableName +"'";
                               var rows = m_formFieldDataSet.Tables[i].Select(expression);

                                if (rows.Any())
                                {

                                var dt = rows.CopyToDataTable();

                                   var firstParam = fields.GetFieldPositions(FieldName);

                                    var a = (firstParam[3] - firstParam[1]);
                                    Logger.Debug(string.Format("creating table with name {0}, width {1}", tableName, a.ToString("#,#####")));
                                    var table = CreateTable(tableName, dt,(firstParam[3]-firstParam[1]));
                                    Logger.Debug(string.Format("created table with width {0}", table.TotalWidth.ToString("#,#####")));


                                    var canvase = stamper.GetOverContent(Convert.ToInt32(firstParam[0]));
                                    table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, firstParam[1], firstParam[4], canvase);
                                    fields.SetField(FieldName, canvase.ToString());
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fields.SetField(FieldName, FieldNameValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and this is the method which fills the table:

```
    private PdfPTable CreateTable( string tableName, DataTable dataTable, float elementWidth)
    {
        int colno = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1;
        int colNameIndex = dataTable.Columns.IndexOf("ShowInTable");
        int rowNo = dataTable.Rows.Count;
        float singleElementWidth = elementWidth / colno;
        float[] elementsWidths = new float[colno];

        for (var c = 0; c < colno; c++)
        {
            elementsWidths[c] = singleElementWidth;
        }


        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(colno);
        table.SetTotalWidth(elementsWidths);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tableName));
        cell.Colspan = colno;
        table.AddCell(cell);

        for (var col = 0; col <= colno; col++)
        {
            if (col != colNameIndex)
            {
                table.AddCell(dataTable.Columns[col].ColumnName);
            }
        }


        for (var r = 0; r <= rowNo -1; r++)
            {
                for (var c =0; c <= colno; c++)
                {
                    if (c != colNameIndex)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(dataTable.Rows[r].ItemArray[c].ToString());
                    }

                }
            }

         return table;
    }
```

When using unit tests with this code , everything works as expected, tables are generated and visible in PDF. When using it as a part of application, Tables are not visible.

Note, only once I managed to create visible table inside PDF generated in application, but it was with different PDF template and different datasource.

I already tried checks in those questions/answers 
[WriteSelectedRows doesnt show a table on PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884164/writeselectedrows-doesnt-show-a-table-on-pdf)
[How do I add table to existing pdf using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168110/how-do-i-add-table-to-existing-pdf-using-itextsharp/14170861#14170861)
and width indeed is different then 0,  and GetOverContent parameter is set to correct page.
Is there some specific setting for PDF template which I need to apply in order to generate tables correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using an old version of iText? Is there a specific reason why you're not using iText 7?

Comment: I am extending current logic to support tables as well (currently supporting only basic fields and images), and the application is a bit older  (also, the product owner doesn't approve upgrading to newer version).

Comment: You are talking about a product. Is this an open source product? If so, where can we download it? If not, please be aware that the open source license doesn't allow the use of iText in a closed source product. When you use iText in a closed source product, a commercial license is needed.

Comment: This is something that I am extending as a proof of concept so it might not be developed further If I didn't succeed, and for current  implementetion I assume that they have a commercial license, otherwise I assume that I'd have more freedom. My idea is that something is wrong with the template.

Comment: If something is wrong with the template, how are people supposed to answer your question if you don't share the template?

Comment: I cannot run the code from your question to reproduce the issue. And even if I could, it most likely would work for me, as you said yourself that your code works in your tests, merely not as "a part of application". Thus, I would assume that the error is in the way the code is integrated in the application, e.g. the `DataTable` might not yet or not anymore be initialized.